# Проблема с калькулятором JS на устройствах iOS (Safari)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, safari, кроссбраузерность

есть калькулятор на сайте (ссылка: [oneservice24.ru/#my-calc](https://oneservice24.ru/#my-calc)). 
Сайт на WordPress'e, плагин калькулятора - ez Form Calculator. Проблема в том, что при выборе "неисправностей" - на iPhone XR, X появляются проблемы с отображением.

При тестировании с других устройств (не на iOS, хотя даже на 6 айфоне всё корректно отображается) всё отображается корректно.

Что я уже сделал:

1) Прописал плавность анимации в стилях.

2) Добавил своим кастомным стилям кроссбраузерные свойства (http://autoprefixer.github.io/)

3) С помощью оптимизации ускорил скорость загрузки сайта на моб. устройствах.

4) Сжал изображения иконок калькулятора.

5) Перевел сайт на PHP 7.1.

6) Увеличил wp-memory-limit до 64mb.

Всё вышеперечисленное не помогло :(

Прикладываю видео:

1) https://cs564416.vkuservideo.net/2/u3899122/videos/6683c08be6.720.mp4

2) https://cs564500.vkuservideo.net/17/u3899122/videos/80e7a4864e.720.mp4

Надеюсь, что объяснил более-менее понятно. Заранее спасибо тем, кто прочитал мою муть и попытался помочь)

*UPDATE* Может ли это происходить из-за большого кол-ва элементов в структуре DOM?

[image: проблема с отображением на iOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оптимизировал CSS + калькулятор разбил по отдельным страницам. Скорее всего проблема возникала из-за большого кол-ва элементов в структуре DOM. Если точнее, то при нажатии на кнопку добавлялся класс "selected" и шло перевычисление стилей.